22.04 and Installing Packages From Local ISO
I seem to be having a few issues installing packages from a locally mounted ISO (ubuntu-22.04-live-server-amd64.iso).
mount -t iso9660 -o loop /root/iso/ubuntu-24.04-live-server-amd64.iso /mnt/ubuntu/
 
cat  ubuntu.sources
Types: deb
deb [trusted=yes] file:///mnt/ubuntu/ noble main contrib
#deb [trusted=yes] file:///mnt/ubuntu/ noble main
#URIs: http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
#Suites: noble noble-updates noble-backports
#Components: main restricted universe multiverse
#Signed-By: /usr/share/keyrings/ubuntu-archive-keyring.gpg
 
Types: deb
#URIs: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/
#Suites: noble-security
#Components: main restricted universe multiverse
#Signed-By: /usr/share/keyrings/ubuntu-archive-keyring.gpg
 
 
apt install p7zip
N: Ignoring file 'ubuntu.sources.bac' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Malformed entry 1 in sources file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ubuntu.sources (URI)
E: The list of sources could not be read.


If you look at the manpage examples, the file uri uses just a single slash - as well, you likely need to comment out the Types: if you are using the one-line format rather than the DEB822 format

This question is similar to: How do I remove a malformed line from my sources.list?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
